# Variables and Filename TCL

Tags: variables, tcl, filenames

I am working on a project for my company and can't figure out how to extract the value from a variable let's call it 'a' and use it in the file name.

So, if the value of a is 1234 then as an example I want the file name to be 1234_abc.pcm  I thought that maybe I could use the dollar sign to read the value from 'a' but that doesn't work and every combination that I could think of using curly and square brackets as well as parentheses have fallen short of the finish line.  Nothing has worked all day.  I end up getting $a_abc.pcm as the file name.  Any thoughts / ideas would be a great help!

Thanks in advance,

ButtahNBred

Comment: The problem is that `a_abc` is a valid variable name, so you have to tell Tcl where your variable stops and the rest of the string begins. (see the [variable substitution rule](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/Tcl.htm#M12))

Comment: I understand that but when I place it into a full path with the file name (i.e. C:\0000\${a}_abc) the recorded file is $a_abc.  It doesn't replace ${a} with the numerical value that user inputs...the value of a is dynamic.  You can look at a as a serial number rather than just a number that remains constant.

Answer (score 3):

I bet you're doing this:

```
set filename "c:\0000\${a}_abc.pcm"
```

The 2nd backslash, which you think is a directory separator, is actually escaping the `$`, preventing variable substitution [*].

Choose one of these alternatives:

```
set filename "c:\\0000\\${a}_abc.pcm"
set filename "c:/0000/${a}_abc.pcm"
set filename [format {c:\0000\%s_abc.pcm} $a]
set filename [file join c: 0000 ${a}_abc.pcm]  ;# my preferred solution
```

Windows handles forward slashes perfectly well)

[*] it's actually worse than that: due to the `\000` you're actually getting a NUL byte. I'm not conversant with Tcl's implementation of strings and what is does with NULs, but:

```
$ tclsh <<< 'set a 1234; puts "c:\0000\${a}_foo"' | od -c
0000000   c   :  \0   0   $   {   a   }   _   f   o   o  \n
0000015
```

Comment: Fortunately, after discussions with people at work we discovered that it was easiest to set the recording directory using this command {C:\0000\ } and then append the serial number so the directory and filename exist.

The forward slashes did not work for us so I guess there was a problem with our software recognizing the forward slashes as directory and filename delimiters.

Comment: I advise using forward slashes (`/`) in the script and then [`file nativename`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/file.htm#M24) to get backslashes when feeding into another program via `exec` (or showing to a user, if you really want to do that).

Comment: In terms of what happens with a NUL, it'll truncate the filename when Windows gets it (assuming you're doing `open`) and the effects will be “interesting” if you feed into `exec`. (There's a subtle interplay of a few things there.) I know that on Unix, it just truncates…

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are looking for something like this?

```
set a "1234"
set suffix "_abc.pcm"
set filename "${a}${suffix}"
```

Comment: Not strictly necessary to use the suffix var: `set filename ${a}_abc.pcm` works just as well and is perhaps a little less cluttered.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't clarify that 'a' in this situation is not static.  It is dynamic and changes based on each run through.  You can look at a as a serial number rather than a constant value.

Answer (score 0):

As Glenn Jackman points out; your problems are probably caused by backslashes.

To avoid these problems you should use the `file` command to construct your filenames -

```
% set a 1234
1234
% set filename [file join c:/ 0000 ${a}_abc.pcm
c:/0000/1234_abc.pcm
% nativeFilename [file join nativename $filename]
c:\0000\1234_abc.pcm
```

If you're going to use the filename within Tcl - e.g. in an `open` statement, you don't need to convert to native format with `file nativename`.

Using the `file` command is essential if you're writing code to be portable between Windows, Unix and Mac. Even if you aren't, it will help avoid backslash problems.

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately, after discussions with people at work we discovered that it was easiest to set the recording directory using this command {C:\0000\ } and then append the serial number so the directory and filename exist.

The forward slashes did not work for us so I guess there was a problem with our software recognizing the forward slashes as directory and filename delimiters.

Comment: External tools probably need backslashes; that's what `file nativename` solves for you (and neatly!)